# Axios delete Bad Request (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I want to delete the data, but also fail. The error message is `400 Bad Request`. In the Backend `allowOrigin` is `true`. How to solve this?

**This the code**

```
export const Admin = () => {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([])
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false)
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMovies = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios(`http://localhost:4001/movies`);
        await setMovies(result.data.data);
        setLoaded(true)
      } catch (err) {
        setErrorMessage(err.response.data)
      }
    }
    fetchMovies();
  }, [])

  const confirmDelete = async (id) => {
    const payload = {
      id: id.toString(),
    }

    await axios.delete(
      'http://localhost:4001/admin/movies/delete',
      {
        data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      }
    )
  }

  return (
    <>
        <Table striped bordered hover>
          <thead>
            ...
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            {movies.map((movie, index) => (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>{index + 1}</td>
                <td>
                  <Link to={`/movies/${movie.id}`} className="text-decoration-none text-black">
                    {movie.title}
                  </Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <Link to={`movies/${movie.id}/edit`} className="text-white text-decoration-none btn btn-warning btn-sm">
                    Edit
                  </Link>
                  {' '}
                  <span
                    className="text-white text-decoration-none btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    onClick={() => confirmDelete(movie.id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </span>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>

        </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

await axios.delete(
'http://localhost:4001/admin/movies/delete',
{
data: payload
}
)

Try giving payload object directly instead of converting to json string